# Kotlin class.java of generic data type

Tags: spring, kotlin, generics

I am quite noob in Kotlin, so here is my question:

I am using `<T> T convert(@Nullable Object source, Class<T> targetType);`
There is a `TestDto<NounDto>` type, which is my `targetType`.
When I try to pass `TestDto<NounDto>::class.java` as a param to `converter.convert(entity, TestDto<NounDto>::class.java)`, I get "Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal" error message.

Is it possible at all to pass this data type? And how if yes?

Thanks in advance for replies!

Comment: Just pass `TestDto::class.java`? Note that types are erased at runtime.

Comment: You cannot use `::class` on generics

Comment: It doesn't work, as I wish, looks like generics and `::class` are contradictory

Comment: `TestDto<NounDto>` is a type, not a class; `TestDto` is a class. So you can only use `::class` with the latter. (As dan1st says, due to type erasure, at runtime all information about generics is lost, and you only have bare classes.)

Comment: In order to use actual types (not just classes), you would need the `convert` function to use `KType` or `Type` instead. Or some kind of wrapper that also has a generic type parameter so it can be used safely in such functions